# How to know whether the SecureField is editing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using `SecureField` to build a login page. However, I notice there is no `onEditingChanged`, so we can't know whether it's become first responder or not. Is there any solution to monitor this event?

Comment: run to that issue as well, did you found a solution? Looks like Apple don't wants observing a "SecureField". I can imagin why, but i need to know it as well :)

Comment: Did you find answer to this problem ? It's 2023 and the it's still the same. Can't determine when `SecureField` is focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model class that holds the variable for secureText value (In your case it should be LoginModel or something like that). Then bind the value to secureField text and add didSet on the Published var in the model. Here is an example:

Model:

```
class SecureFieldModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var secureText = "" {
        didSet {
            print(secureText)
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@ObservedObject var model = SecureFieldModel()
    
struct LoginView: View {
   var body: some View {
      SecureField("Type your text here", text: $model.secureText)
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you may misunderstand my question. Ff the textfield is just focus, no text yet, we can't get the event.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you may misunderstand my question. If the textfield is just
> focus, no text yet, we can't get the event. – RayChen 3 hours ago

Mantas answer slightly modified. "firing" when the input text has content or it is active:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model = SecureFieldModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        // No info when focus removed
        SecureField("Type your text here", text: $model.secureText)
            .onTapGesture { // when active
                self.model.textFieldActivated()
            }

        // Do something when focus removed
        SecureField("Type your text here", text: $model.secureText, onCommit: {print("Commited and focus removed")})
            .onTapGesture { // when active
                self.model.textFieldActivated()
            }
    }
}

class SecureFieldModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var secureText = "" {
        didSet {
            // if text
            if secureText.count >= 1 {
                print(secureText)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldActivated() {
        if secureText.count >= 1 {
            print(secureText)
        } else {
            print("is active")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will lead to the issue that you don't know when focus is removed. You have to handle it somewhere else and this can be messy.

Comment: I don't see your issue. Just add a ```onCommit``` to the textfield. I modified the code accordingly.

Comment: `onCommit` is only used when the user presses the return key. Means wen tapping on another textfield, or closing the keyboard somehow else its not activating the closure